# how can I fix error: hd0 out of disk?

Tags: boot, 12.04, grub2

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a netbook - Acer AS 1410.

After a download session, I restarted the computer and it said:

```
error: hd0 out of disk. Press any key to continue...
```

I pressed everything, but it's just frozen there.

Any idea what's wrong with it and what I can do to fix it? I haven't been able to run my computer at all since it's frozen like that. Help please!

I booted the live cd and ran `sudo fdisk -lu` into terminal, and here's what it gave me:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9a696263

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda3            2048   117229567    58613760    5  Extended
/dev/sda5   *    71647232   109039615    18696192   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       109041664   117229567     4093952   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7            4096    71645183    35820544   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

I am somewhat of a beginner in this, so don't know what this means. any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: So it doesn't open a command line, it just freezes and you cannot input anything, right?

Comment: Boot the livecd and run `sudo fdisk -lu` and edit your question to show the output.

Comment: Try rebooting into recovery mode and select [repair packages](http://s1296.photobucket.com/user/joetjo/media/2013-06-24_0825_zps27848c52.png.html).

Comment: @edwin , that's right.

Comment: @mitch , I went into recovery mode, but there was nothing to select, it went into this long analysis, like a ticker tape, until finally it said: "BusyBox v1. 18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands." I tried typing "dpkg" in it, but it said not found.... I typed in "help" and a long list of commands came up that I have no idea what they do

Comment: Have you removed/resized partitions? Try booting into the live DVD (or USB) and [reinstalling grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal) into your root partition.

Comment: Could please start a live DVD/USB, mount all the internal file systems, run `df -h` and `df -i` and include the output in your question? That should provide more insight into what exactly might be "full" here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've upgraded many times, and you have a lot of old linux kernals filling up your grub partition.

I think you're going to have to boot from a live DVD or USB, mount the HDs boot partition, see if it is indeed full, and if that's the case, manually delete a couple of old kernals.

If you haven't got a backup, you might copy your ~/ to a safe place first.

Comment: This is grub saying that the filesystem extends beyond the end of the disk and thus can not be read, not that it is full.

Comment: @marc, how do i mount the HDs boot partition and manually delete kernals?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a Live-Usb.

Completed load session:

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/sda5
fsck -y /dev/sda5
umount /dev/sda6
fsck -y /dev/sda6
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
umount /mnt
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem.

```
error: hd0,msdos1 out of disk.
grub rescue>
```

The reason is that the RAM modules did not fully enter the slot. I removed the modules and installed them in a new way, checked that they fully entered the slots, and were locked with locks.
After these operations, the system boots normally.

```
P.S: CPU: Pentium 4, 2.4 GHz. MotherBoard: ASUS P4P800; OS Linux MINT 10 «Julia» (32-bit)
```